# Homeomorphism and fixed point of $F\circ G$

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

If $F\in\textrm{Homeo}_+(\mathbb{T}^1)$ and $G\in\textrm{Homeo}_+(\mathbb{T}^1)$ commute and have each one a fixed point then $F\circ G$ has also a fixed point. I am wondering how we can apply the concept of rotation number to show that.

Thank you so much

Comment: The winding number can be computed at any point on $T^1$.  Choose one of the fixed points, write down the definition of winding number for $F \circ G$, and use commutativity along with the meaning of "fixed point."

Comment: Thus, the conclusion should be $\rho(G)=\rho(F)=\rho(F\circ G)=0$, right?